# Compare the columns of the two files

Tags: awk

I have a two files and trying compare the files on the basis of columns

File_1

```
CALL_3  CALL_1
CALL_2  CALL_5
CALL_3  CALL_2
CALL_1  CALL_4
```

File_2

```
CALL_1   GAP:A  GAP:G
CALL_3   GAP:C  GAP:Q  GAP:R 
CALL_5   GAP:R  GAP:A
CALL_4   GAP:C  GAP:D  GAP:A  GAP:W
CALL_2   GAP:C  GAP:R  GAP:A
```

I want to print only those interaction from file_1 having atleast one GAP_id is comman between these two.

Expected output

```
CALL_2  CALL_5  GAP:A GAP:R
CALL_3  CALL_2  GAP:C GAP:R
CALL_1  CALL_4  GAP:A
```

I tried the following :

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
a[$1]=($1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $5 OFS $6 OFS $7 OFS $8 OFS $9)
next 
}
($1 in a)&&($2 in a) {
print a[$1],a[$2]
}' File_2 File_1
```

It is working good for fixed number of columns. But number of columns is not fixed in file_2 (more than 1000 columns). How to get the expected output?

Comment: What about `CALL_1  CALL_4` ? They both have GAP:A

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, I corrected the expected output section of the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  val=$1
  $1=""
  $0=$0
  $1=$1
  a[val]=$0
  next
}
{
  val=""
  num1=split(a[$1],array1," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num1;i++){
    array3[array1[i]]
  }
  num2=split(a[$2],array2," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num2;i++){
    array4[array2[i]]
  }
  for(k in array3){
    if(k in array4){
      val=(val?val OFS:"")k
    }
  }
  if(val){
    print $0,val
  }
  val=""
  delete array1
  delete array2
  delete array3
  delete array4
}
'  Input_file2   Input_file1
```

Output will be as follows.

```
CALL_2  CALL_5 GAP:A GAP:R
CALL_3  CALL_2 GAP:C GAP:R
CALL_1  CALL_4 GAP:A
```

---

---

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                  ##Starting awk program here.
FNR==NR{                               ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE for first Input_file is being read.
  val=$1                               ##Creating a variable named val whose value is $1 of current line.
  $1=""                                ##Nullifying $1 here.
  $0=$0                                ##Re-assigning value of current line to itself, so that initial space will be removed.
  $1=$1                                ##Re-assigning value of current line to itself, so that initial space will be removed.
  a[val]=$0                            ##Creating an array named a whose index is val and value is $0.
  next                                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  val=""                               ##Nullifying variable val here.
  num1=split(a[$1],array1," ")         ##splitting array a with index $1 to array1 and having its total number in num1.
  for(i=1;i<=num1;i++){                ##Starting a for loop from i=1 till value of num1
    array3[array1[i]]                  ##Creating an array named array3 with index of array1 with index i.
  }
  num2=split(a[$2],array2," ")         ##splitting array a with index $2 to array2 and having its total number in num2.
  for(i=1;i<=num2;i++){                ##Starting a for loop from i=1 till value of num2.
    array4[array2[i]]                  ##Creating an array named array4 with value of array2 with index i.
  }
  for(k in array3){                    ##Traversing through array3 here.
    if(k in array4){                   ##Checking condition if k which is index of  array3 is present in array4 then do following.
      val=(val?val OFS:"")k            ##Creating variable named val whose value is variable k with concatenating its own value each time to it.
    }
  }
  if(val){                             ##Checking condition if variable val is NOT NULL then do following.
    print $0,val                       ##Printing current line and variable val here.
  }
  val=""                               ##Nullifying variable val here.
  delete array1                        ##Deleting array1 here.
  delete array2                        ##Deleting array2 here.
  delete array3                        ##Deleting array3 here.
  delete array4                        ##Deleting array4 here.
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1            ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for arrays of arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        gaps[$1][$i]
    }
    next
}
{
    common = ""
    for (gap in gaps[$1]) {
        if (gap in gaps[$2]) {
            common = common OFS gap
        }
    }
    if ( common != "" ) {
        print $0 common
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
CALL_2  CALL_5 GAP:A GAP:R
CALL_3  CALL_2 GAP:C GAP:R
CALL_1  CALL_4 GAP:A
```

With any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    key = $1
    sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")
    gaps[key] = $0
    next
}
{
    mkSet(gaps[$1],gaps1)
    mkSet(gaps[$2],gaps2)
    common = ""
    for (gap in gaps1) {
        if (gap in gaps2) {
            common = common OFS gap
        }
    }
    if ( common != "" ) {
        print $0 common
    }
}
function mkSet(str,arr, i,tmp) {
    delete arr
    split(str,tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        arr[tmp[i]]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
CALL_2  CALL_5 GAP:A GAP:R
CALL_3  CALL_2 GAP:C GAP:R
CALL_1  CALL_4 GAP:A
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it in bash with coreutils. A oneliner:

```
join -12 -21 <(join -11 -21 <(sort file_1) <(sort file_2) | sort -k2) <(sort file_2) | xargs -l1 bash -c 'a=$(<<<"${@:3}" tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq -d | tr "\n" " "); if [ -n "$a" ]; then printf "%s %s %s\n" "$1" "$2" "$a"; fi' --
```

Or a bit more lines:

```
join -12 -21 <(
     join -11 -21 <(sort file_1) <(sort file_2) | sort -k2
) <(
     sort file_2
) | 
xargs -l1 bash -c '
  a=$(<<<"${@:3}" tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq -d | tr "\n" " ");
  if [ -n "$a" ]; then
     printf "%s %s %s\n" "$1" "$2" "$a"
  fi
' --
```

1. Join file_1 with file_2 on the first fields.
2. Join the result from point 1 on field 2 with file_2 again
3. Then for each line:

   1. Get only the duplicates of the GAP* parts
   2. If there are any duplicates print the CALL_* with the duplicates

Results in:

```
CALL_2 CALL_3 GAP:C GAP:R 
CALL_4 CALL_1 GAP:A 
CALL_5 CALL_2 GAP:A GAP:R
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk this is straightforward:

```
$ awk '(NR==FNR){$1=$1;a[$1]=$0;next}
       {str=strt=$1 OFS $2}
       {split(a[$1],b,OFS)}
       {for(i in b) if(index(a[$2] OFS, OFS b[i] OFS)) str=str OFS a[$2]} 
       (str!=strt){print str}' file2 file1
```

**How does this work:**

1. **`(NR==FNR){$1=$1;a[$1]=$0;next}`**

   The first line buffers `file2` in an associative array `a[key]=value` where `key` is the first element and `value` the full line. Eg.

   ```
   a["CALL_1"]="CALL_1 GAP:A GAP:G"
   ```

   Remark, that we substituted all `FS` into `OFS` using `$1=$1`.
2. **`{str=strt=$1 OFS $2}`**

   This just stores `CALL_1 CALL_2` in the variable `str`
3. **`{split(a[$1],b,OFS)}`**: split the buffered line into array `b`
4. **`{for(i in b) if(index(a[$2] OFS, OFS b[i] OFS)) str=str OFS a[$2]}`**

   For all entries in array `b`, check if the string `OFS b[i] OFS` is found in the string `a[$2] OFS`. We add the extra `OFS` to ensure field matches. We do test for values like `OFS CALL_2 OFS`, but this will never match. This is a tiny overhead, but fixing this would create much more overhead.

A more optimised version would read:

```
$ awk '(NR==FNR){k=$1;$1="";a[k]=$1;c[k]=NF-1;next}
       {str=strt=$1 OFS $2}
       (c[$1]< c[$2]) {split(substr(a[$1],2),b,OFS);s=a[$2] OFS}
       (c[$1]>=c[$2]) {split(substr(a[$2],2),b,OFS);s=a[$1] OFS}
       {for(i in b) if(index(s, OFS b[i] OFS)) str=str OFS a[$2]} 
       (str!=strt){print str}' file2 file1
```

Comment: It print the whole file_1